# How do you type out the square volume in Python

Tags: python

Given sphere_radius and pi, compute the volume of a sphere and assign sphere_volume with the volume. Volume of sphere = (4.0 / 3.0) π r3

Sample output with input: 1.0

Sphere volume: 4.19

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this

```py
from math import pi

def main():
    sphere_radius = float(input("Enter the radius of a sphere: "))
    sphere_volume = (4/3) * pi * sphere_radius ** 3

    print(f"Sphere volume: {sphere_volume}")

main()
```

EDIT:

Output

```
Enter the radius of a sphere: 1
Sphere volume: 4.1887902047863905
```

Surrounding the `sphere_volume` calculation with `round()` you can limit the answer to two decimal places

```py
sphere_volume = round((4/3) * pi * sphere_radius ** 3, 2)
```

Output

```
Enter the radius of a sphere: 1
Sphere volume: 4.19
```

It was suggested that I edit my answer changing `(4/3)` to `(4/3.0)` to address integer division. My code is accurate to the current version of python since python 2 is EOL. As such, by default in python 3 integer division will return a float making the change unnecessary. Albeit it is good practice, especially if working with other languages.

Likewise my print statement was said to be incorrect. I suggest running the code before making claims. Also take a look at python documentation on F-Strings [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)